# How do I open file:///sdcard on Galaxy Tab?

Tags: android, file, google-chrome, galaxy-tab

On my android phone I have alwaysbeen able to play HTML games in chrome or other browsers by using the file:///sdcard/ directory.

If you try to open the files with the default file explorer when it opens in the web browser it is in a fake content folder and none of the images will load. On my new Galaxy Tablet trying to navigate to file:///sdcard will either search Google for the term file:///sdcard, or if there is no automatic search, says it doesn't have permissions. If I go to permissions,there is no option to give any app permissions for local files. I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out how to access my local html files from the browser directly so they can load associated images.

Comment: Are you a programmer? Is this a programming question?

Comment: This is not a programming question, I am asking as a user of a galaxy tab trying to play an html game from a local file.

Comment: See the answer here https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220400/2241

Comment: That answer does not s0lve my problem, as I am unable to access the directories listed there either. Any attempt to access a file directory searches for the directory instead.